# Python applying iterative linregress

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am working to get to the following output.

Dataset first:

[image]

I have been using the following code to get to the output but failing every time:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df=pd.read_excel('I:/Python/Data/Copy.xlsx')

grouped = df.groupby('Test Event')

for test_event, g in grouped:
    print('Test Event: {}'.format(test_event))
df_np=np.array(g)

x=np.array(df_np[:,3],dtype=float)
y=np.array(df_np[:,4],dtype=float)

for i, pair in enumerate(zip(x, y)):

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(np.delete(x,i),np.delete(y,i))

    print('slope', slope, 'for data without pair', i, ':', pair)
```

---

This is what is needed: For every Test Event, there is a unique ID. For every Unique ID, there is a slope. The way the slope is obtained is mentioned in Comment section of the image.

How do I go about solving this issue?

In jupyter notebook, the final output needed is as follows:

It gives output only for 'data without pair 9' for test events 111 and 112.

I need 'data without pair 0',..., 'data without pair 9' as outputs per event.
[image: Output]

Comment: What output do you get with your code?

Comment: @Stuart, I added the output I am getting using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: @Stuart, as can be seen from the output image, the code is only looking at pair 9 for event 111 and event 112. I was expecting it to go from pair 0 to pair 9.

Comment: Check that the right columns are being selected for `x` and `y` - remember the numbering starts at 0. It should possibly be `x=np.array(df_np[:,3]...` and
 `y=np.array(df_np[:,4]...`. Also check your tabulation (it seems to have gone missing in the above)

Comment: @Stuart, I was using 3 and 4. In the code I missed to finally keep the final edited version. Thanks for pointing out. I edited the code. The results still remain the same. What do you mean by tabulation gone missing?

Comment: I mean there is no indentation (tabs) showing in your code above. I assume you have indentation in the code you are actually using. Please try to add the indentation in the code above so that it matches. That could be a source of the problem.

Comment: @Stuart, I added indentation to the code and the output did change. I can see all data for TestEvent 112 but no data seen for TestEvent111. Can you please show where do I indent so that I get data for both TestEvent 111 and 112.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your code to be indented as follows to ensure there is a loop within a loop:

```
for test_event, g in grouped:
    # loop over the groups
    print('Test Event: {}'.format(test_event))
    df_np=np.array(g)
    x=np.array(df_np[:,3],dtype=float)
    y=np.array(df_np[:,4],dtype=float)
    for i, pair in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
        # loop over the rows within each group
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(np.delete(x,i),np.delete(y,i))
        print('slope', slope, 'for data without pair', i, ':', pair)
```

A slightly simpler way to do this, without having to convert to arrays and zip, would be:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Test Event')
df["slope"] = np.NaN
for test_event, g in grouped:
    print('Test Event: {}'.format(test_event))
    for i in g.index:
        others = g.loc[g.index != i, ["x-axis", "y-axis"]]
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(others)
        print ("slope", slope, 'for data without pair', i)
        df.loc[i, "slope"] = slope
```

This also adds the slopes to the dataframe.

Comment: this solution did work. Yes, second solution is way better than the first one I was trying. Which part of code to edit, if now rather than 1 point, I need to delete two points and calculate slope of the other 8 points?

Comment: I mean for event 111, if I remove points 0,1;0,2;0,3;...;0,9 then I get 10 slopes. Similar needs to be done for 1,2;1,3;1,4...1,9. If this is out of the scope of current question, I will create a new one.

Comment: With a further nested loop `for j in g.index:`, or using e.g. `itertools.combinations(g.index, len(g.index)-2))` to get all the combinations of indices removing two points each time. Ask a new question if you need more detail.

Comment: yes I am asking a new question since it can be very lengthy to explain here. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: asked the new question.

Comment: it may help to include a link in your new question back to this one

Comment: Oh sure @Stuart

Comment: done. Seems OK?